# Why is the "not a real question" close reason unavailable?

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

I was going to close [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/242/are-the-game-systems-advertised-by-pickup-artists-effective-or-are-they-elabor) as "not a real question":

> **not a real question:** It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

As Fabian said in the comments, it's simply unclear what is being asked.

Unfortunately, that close reason isn't available here. Is that an oversight or a bug, or is it intentional? If it's intentional, why is that? It's a very useful close questions at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an oversight on our part, a result of how new sites and their metas are created (we don't want this close reason on a meta).  It's now fixed, you'll see the option available in the close menu starting...now!